# How to import/export my Realm Database from/to my iPhone app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have created an app with Xcode based on Realm DB, but now I don not know how the user can export/import the Realm db file. I can not access to my device(Iphone) from Realm Browser.

Is there a way to do this? Either by code or with Realm browser?

Comment: Maybe with Realm Studio?

Comment: You should be able to access it using Realm Browser. What problem are you facing there exactly ?

Comment: Have you enabled file sharing so you can see your documents on iTunes? If this is for testing purposes that would be enough. If you need this functionality for users maybe you could let them attach the file in an email to be sent with MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: Well... I do not know how to look for my Realm DB in my device. I was trying to transfer the file with file sharing, but my App does not appear in the List

Comment: I was trying to use Realm Studio, however I can not accésits to my devices.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could help you:

On Xcode, with your device plugged, do the command CMD+SHIFT+2. You will see a list of your installed apps. Selection your app then click on wheel [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPk5P.png)

You will be able to download or replace the container of your app where you will find your Realm db file in AppData/Documents.